# How to add a checkedit control to a gridview in devexpress programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, devexpress, gridcontrol

I want to bind a `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` which is then bound to the `GridControl`. How do I add a **checkedit** control once the `DataTable` has been created?

I have a Devexpress windows application which in the designer,

1. GridControl
2. BindingSource

This `GridControl`'s datasource is the bindingsource1.

I have the following in the page_Load event,

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");

        dt.Rows.Add("rambo", 60);
        dt.Rows.Add("Arnie", 35);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
        gridView1.RefreshData();

        gridView1.Columns.Add(
            new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn()
            {
                Caption = "Selected",
                ColumnEdit = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit() { },
                Visible = true,
            }
            );
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you are very close.  Try the following changes:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");

        dt.Rows.Add("rambo", 60);
        dt.Rows.Add("Arnie", 35);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
        gridControl1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        gridView1.RefreshData();

        gridView1.Columns.Add(
            new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn()
            {
                Caption = "Selected",
                ColumnEdit = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit() { },
                VisibleIndex = 0,
                UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean
            }
            );
```

Notice that all I changed was the visible index and setting the unbound column type.  Technically, I believe all you need is the visibleIndex property set to where you would like it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a column in your grid to have a checkbox as an edit control, you can achieve this by adding a column in your DataTable that contains boolean values. The following works for me.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(System.Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Selected", typeof(System.Boolean));

dt.Rows.Add("rambo", 60, true);
dt.Rows.Add("Arnie", 35, false);

gridView1.OptionsBehavior.AutoPopulateColumns = true;
bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
gridControl1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Comment: Hey Ken, thanks for this. Unfortunately it's not quite what I am after. The result is fine but I need to add the CheckEdit control separately. Good effort though